# Java Puzzle Solving Algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, puzzle

I need help with writing code that can take an integer and up to 50 grids as input and calculate the minimum number of clicks needed (from an all white starting position) to achieve the grid(s) that was input from a user.

I'm trying to write an algorithm for a logic puzzle in which you have a square grid of 3×3 cells. Each cell is initially either white or black. When you click on a square it flips the color of that square and the colors of its four immediate east, west north and south neighbors that exist.
The problem is to find the minimum number of cell clicks to transform a grid of all white cells into the input grid (which is always possible). You cannot rotate the grid.

The first value in the input file is an integer P(0<P≤50) on a line by itself giving the number of problems to solve. For each of the P problems, 3 lines of 3 characters describe the input grid. The characters in the grid descriptions are ‘*’ (for black) and ‘.’ (for white).

For each problem output a single integer giving the minimum number of clicks necessary to transform a grid of all white cells into the pattern given in the input.

Input 1 Input 2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oI5JE.png

| Sample Input 1 | Sample Output 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| *.. | 3 |
| **. |  |
| *.. |  |
| *** |  |
| *.. |  |
| ..* |  |

I've written this code so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CubePuzzle {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many cubes do you want to solve?");
        int usersInt = sc.nextInt();

        if (usersInt < 1 || usersInt > 50){
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= usersInt; i++){
            sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextInt();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your question? It looks as though your code may have been truncated.

Comment: Okay, what is your question? Also it seems incomplete

Comment: I don't know how to write code that will give me the output that I want as specified in my description. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How to write code when you don't know how to write code:

Write out in your own words **(pseudocode)** a series of instructions that do what you want to do.  You can put in bits of code if you already have some.

That will suggest **inputs** and some **data structures** to store the information as you or the program work with it.

**Walk through your pseudocode** with some simple example and track on paper, or in a file, how the algorithm progresses.  Refine it based on things you discover.

Then start entering it as code.  Keep walking through and refining.  If you hit a point where you want to store something a certain way and are not sure, then you will have a **more specific question** to ask and you will get a more specific answer.  Likewise if you want to manipulate some data and don't know how.

To find something like a minimum number of steps to reach a goal, you may have to use a **search tree and back tracking** (which can be done without implementing a rigorous API-quality binary search tree).  Like the program tries one way and gets to a point where the number of steps exceeds a number already found to work in another path. So it would abandon that way and try others to beat the current "winner".

Do look at the problem and see if there are **mathematical properties** that can cut down the work.  You might be able to shorten steps or abandon loser paths earlier, etc.  Like whether reflections or rotations are equivalent and eliminate paths immediately.  Stuff like that.

By working through some examples, you might find that you can class the patterns into groups just by looking at them without working through steps.  Like if a pattern has a certain characteristic (maybe it is some number of black squares or some number of adjoined squares of one colour, etc.) then the minimum steps is two otherwise it is three.  I haven't looked at it closely.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was asked this question too.

my algorithm is like this:

1. we get n from user.
   n = how many puzzle they have.
2. In a loop repeating for n times, we get input character from user in 3 sets like '*..' and '*..' and '*..'. then we put 9 inputs in an array.
3. In every loop check if it is all '.' (white) (with method 'every' in javascript)
4. if output of method 'every' in item 3 was false, we start clicking. We make a parameter named 'max' and 'cell' and count how many black cells are around each cells and put the maximum count into 'max' and location of cell into 'cell'.
5. Now, we know the cell with maximum black cells around it, so we start toggling (with Bool=!Bool) that cell and all cells around it. We define 'counter' and add 1 to it in every loop.
6. we do item 3,4,5 again and again till the output of 'every' in item 3 becomes 'true', then we show 'counter' as result.

it works when there is only one cell surrounding with maximum black cells around it. if there are more than one cell surrounding equal maximum black cells around, I do not know what to chose for clicking!